# Live HTTP header equivalent for WebSocket protocol

Tags: browser, websocket, protocols

Are there any browser extensions for inspecting WebSocket traffic as there are for "normal" HTTP traffic?

Some background: Having used the Firefox "Live HTTP headers" extension for years, it really helped me to better understand HTTP and has been a great aid in developing advanced web applications. As I'm now in the middle of developing a real-time web application with node.js and socket.io, a similar tool for WebSocket traffic would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out: [Inspecting WebSocket Traffic with Chrome Developer Tools](http://blog.kaazing.com/2012/05/09/inspecting-websocket-traffic-with-chrome-developer-tools/)

It contains even a video about how to do it.